# What is the intuitive explanation of the Intertwining Operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, representation-theory

There are very few online resources explaining the [Intertwining Operator](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Intertwining_operator) and none make much sense. They all seem to say something about representation theory and groups and they came up when I was reading about isospin. I was wondering if somebody could give me an explanation of what they are, mathematically and what they represent in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Where did you come across "the intertwining operator" in the context of physics? Perhaps you find it difficult because "intertwiner" is often just a name for a [morphism of representations/equivariant map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory#Equivariant_maps_and_isomorphisms).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given I know the answer to my question I might as well answer it. The source I was using at the time: http://math.ucr.edu/~huerta/guts/node4.html#sec:isospin

In this context the Hilbert space is being treated as a group and each particle has its own group representation. The intertwiner here represents the force applied to the particles in the space. Furthermore, because this discusses isospin: the force must be invariant.  So an intertwiner is used to represent the force because it respects the group action.